# Is there a way to do basic math on little endian byte integers in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

In python, imagine that we have an integer saved as a little endian byte object and now we want to add it by 1 at each iteration. Let's take the following code as an example:

```
import struct
from time import time_ns as time

rng = range(0, int(1e8))
k = len(rng)
_intgr = 25468

intgr = _intgr
start = time()
for i in rng:
    bb   = struct.pack("<L", intgr)
    # do something on bb
    intgr += 1
end = time()
tot = (end-start)
it  = tot/k #Nano Secs
print('Total time(s)       :', tot/1e9, '(s)')
print('Each iteration takes:', it, '(ns)')
```

Which takes ~400 ns on my CPU per iteration. I am wondering if it is the most effective way of doing this in python. Is not there a direct method to do basic math on byte objects so I do not have to call `struct.pack` at each iteration?

I have seen codes where they do math and also bit-wise operation on byte objects like the one of the following:

```
bb = struct.pack('<L', 100)

cc = bb[0] << 4
dd = bb[0] + 1
```

Is this capable of improving performance in the previous example code?

Comment: Couldn't you simply do the arithmetic in whatever is native, then convert the result to little-endian? Or maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: I have to do something on `bb` at each iteration for which `bb` should be little endian byte. Because it will be appended to another byte and then will be hashed using `hashlib`.